# Is that an 'activation chip' in a knife, and if so what could it accomplish?

Tags: fast-and-furious-franchise, hobbs-and-shaw

While rewatching *Hobbs and Shaw* I noticed something interesting in the scene where Shaw's sister is hacking into the glove before the big island battle.

[image: computer reading "access granted" to various weapons]

Is that not a picture of a knife in the third row of weapons? Assuming that it is, what could an 'activation chip' accomplish in a knife? Anything more fancy that keeping a switch blade from popping out, electrifying the blade, or something like that?

Rather than a knife could that be an image of something else? I don't remember seeing anything during the film that looks like it could represent... Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I cannot guarantee it, it does look like a knife, and given the apparent handle to blade proportion (At least from the resolution appearance), I would believe it to be some variant on an injection knife.

This [type of knife](https://www.knifecenter.com/item/WIWASPKA/wasp-injection-knife-fixed-bead-blast-blade-black-neoprene-handle) contains a CO2 cartridge (Or other propellant, there are different versions depending on military/civilian/who's building it), and the net effect is that it injects a large volume of air/other into the target, at extremely cold temperatures that can freeze the flesh that it comes into contact with.